# ProgressIndicator wraps content on page

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Im creating an app where the startpage is an login screen. When user enter their credentials and finally taps the login button an Progressindicator Dialog is being shown. The dialog is based on an Window Popup. The window and the indicator works like a charm but there is one problem. The indicator is wraping the content on the page. So if you for example entered the wrong credentials and tapped the login button the inticator will dissapear to give the user one more chance to enter their right credentials. But when the indicator dissapear the Rememember Me Checkbox position is changed, it's getting placed over the login button. It seems like the Indicator Dialog is wraping the content on the page. Im a pretty good css & html developer so i wonder if there are something like in css called z-index or is it possible to set the position of the checkbox to absolute so its position aren't based upon other elements position. I used this guide to make this indicator.

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/20/creating-progress-dialog-for-wp7.aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. As i copied the sample code from the orginal project to my own there was a few variables that i had to change the value of to work with my project. Including the height and the width of the object and so on. Anyway, it works like a charm now.